# Trying to duplicate extruded windows up the face of a building

Tags: vertices, extrude, duplicate

I'm using trying to learn blender (3.4) and I'm having an issue with duplicating my extruded windows up the face of my building, I'm just not quite sure how to.

Here is the face of my building:
[image: Building face]

And here are the windows I'd like to duplicate to the top:
[image: windows]

I tried just removing the face of my building and then shift+D up to the top, which did technically work. But then none of my vertices were connected to the rest of the building. I'm just not sure of the proper way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do it but you could do it the way you're doing it, just enable the *Auto Merge* option and the *Split Edges & Faces* options and, thanks to the last option, the duplicated faces will merge with the adjacent:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, perfect.